# Send a stream of bits down a usb data line

Tags: c++, c, linux, libusb

All I want to do is send some data down a specific data line in a usb cable.
I'm currently trying to use linux, c/c++, and libusb, however between getting libusb working, linking the library, and actually building it, everything seems to fail.

Is there an entirely easier way to go about doing such a simple task?

Comment: That's not how USB works. If you want that behavior, you're looking at RS-232. USB exchanges packets, and turning a packet into volts on wires is typically handled completely in hardware.

Comment: As MSalters pointed out, that's just not how USB works. Read [the Wikipedia page on USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB), carefully. Don't just look at and go "oh, USB, yeah, I need to use that to send bits down this wire": read it. Read it and think how how what it says affects what you want to do. Try to express what you want to do in terms of what the page says about how USB works. You might realize "that's hard, it doesn't seem to fit very well", which is what I hope.

Comment: If you essentially want to use USB like you would RS232 and send bytes down a 'com' port then that is not particularly difficult _in concept_.  All you would need is support for the CDC/ACM USB class and you can have what appears to be an RS232 port.  OK so it's not _simple_, but it's only like sending data over ethernet by opening a socket in that the mass of protocol complexity is hidden from you.  Unfortunately my experience was in writing an embedded USB stack and I have no idea about the linux implementations or class support or how to get it to build.